# File download authentication in flask-uploads

Tags: python, flask, flask-uploads

Is there a possibility to force authentication of files served by [Flask-Uploads](https://github.com/srusskih/flask-uploads/blob/0.1.3/flaskext/uploads.py#L433) or at least disable this route?

```
@uploads_mod.route('/<setname>/<path:filename>')
def uploaded_file(setname, filename):
    config = current_app.upload_set_config.get(setname)
    if config is None:
        abort(404)
    return send_from_directory(config.destination, filename)
```

It seems that any file that is uploaded can be downloaded by any (even not logged in) user.

Or only possibility is to use custom implementation as described in [Flask Uploading Files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Flask-Uploads does not offer a way to change how the route behaves.  You do not need to give up Flask-Uploads though, you just need to replace the view with your own version.

Assuming you're using Flask-Login and all you want is a simple `login_required` check, you can just replace the function in `app.view_functions` with the wrapped version.

```
from flask_login import login_required

app.view_functions['_uploads.uploaded_file'] = login_required(app.view_functions['_uploads.uploaded_file'])
```

If you want something more complex, write your own view and replace with that instead.  You can use `app.endpoint` to decorate the function instead of using `app.view_functions` directly.

```
@app.endpoint('_uploads.uploaded_file')
@login_required
def my_uploaded_file(setname, filename):
    # do custom stuff
```